# {"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key on Open Weather API error using Moya

Tags: ios, swift, openweathermap, moya

I used moya to create an API request to openweatherAPI. Now the return on Postman seems to be ok but API calls on X-code returns:

> 401: Invalid API key

I have tried most ways to see what actually is wrong. But I don't seem to find the answer.

```swift
import Foundation
import Moya
import UIKit

enum WeatherAPI {
    
    case showCurrentWeather(cityName: String)
    case showForcasedWeather(cityName: String)
}

extension WeatherAPI: TargetType {
   
    var task: Task {
        switch self {
        case .showCurrentWeather(cityName: let cityName):
            let params = ["q":cityName , "APPID": Constants.WEATHER_API_KEY]
            return .requestParameters(parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        case .showForcasedWeather(cityName: let cityName):
             let params = ["q":cityName , "APPID": Constants.WEATHER_API_KEY]
            return .requestParameters(parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        }
    }
    
    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5")!
    }
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .showCurrentWeather:
            return "/weather"
        case .showForcasedWeather:
            return "/forecast"
        }
    }
    
    var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .showCurrentWeather:
            return .get
        case .showForcasedWeather:
            return .get
        }}
    
    var sampleData: Data {
        return Data()
    }
    
    var headers: [String : String]? {
        switch self {
        case .showCurrentWeather:
            return ["Content-type":"application/json"]
        case .showForcasedWeather:
            return ["Content-type":"application/json"]
        }
    }
}
```

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&APPID=dbd3b02d8958d62185d02e944cd5f522

works fine on Postman and browsers.

X-Code returns

> "cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}

Answer (score 1):

You should change this *JSONEncoding.default* to *URLEncoding.default* in Task variable.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this works for you or not, you can give it a try.
Change "appId" with "key"
like:
fetch(`//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&key=${api_key}`)

it worked for me this way!