# php curl does not seem to send the intended POST variables

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to retrieve a post from a simple POST to api.openweathermap.org.

The URL post should like like: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4215110&units=metric&appid=my_api_key

The php code I'm using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
  
<?php

define('WEATHER_CITY_CODE', 4215110) ;    // Peachtree City, GA
define('WEATHER_UNITS', 'imperial') ;     // or 'metric' or 'standard'
define('WEATHER_API_KEY', 'my_api_key') ; // Not the real key

$request = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" ;
$requestVariables = Array('id' => WEATHER_CITY_CODE
                        , 'units' => WEATHER_UNITS
                        , 'appid' => WEATHER_API_KEY
                         ) ;
printf("Request query parameters should be: %s?%s\n", $request, http_build_query($requestVariables)) ;
$streamVerboseHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+') ;
$ch = curl_init($request) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $streamVerboseHandle) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $requestVariables )) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true) ;

$weather_response = curl_exec($ch) ;
//if ($weather_response === FALSE)
    {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n",
           curl_errno($ch),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)))
           ;
    rewind($streamVerboseHandle);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($streamVerboseHandle);
    echo "cUrl verbose information:\n",
         htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "\n";
    }
curl_close($ch) ;

try {
    $response_arr = json_decode($weather_response, true, 3, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR) ;
    print_r($response_arr) ;
    }

catch (Exception $e) {
    $response_file = "weather-response.json" ;
    file_put_contents($response_file, $weather_response) ;
    $lov->writeLogLine("Exception from send-sms.php: " . $e->getMessage()) ;
    $lov->writeLogLine("Response text is: '" . $weather_response . "'"
                     , false, null, false, false) ;
    $lov->writeLogLine("Response saved in " . $response_file) ;
    throw new Exception("Failure in send-sms.php") ;
    }


?>
```

When I run this code (even if the WEATHER_API_KEY value is set correctly, I get the following response:

```
Array
(
    [cod] => 401
    [message] => Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.
)
```

Even if the correct API key is used.  (Note: I can copy the value in the "Request query paraemters..." line and paste them into a browser to get the correct results without error.

So I added the curl debug code you see above, and it seems to indicate that curl is not sending my parameters. (see the **POST /data/2.5/weather HTTP/1.1** below.)  I'm not sure why.  While I'm not accustomed to using (nor needing) that curl debug information, it seems to me that I should see **/data/2.5/weather?id=4...** in its place.

I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779613/cod401-message-invalid-api-key-on-open-weather-api-error-using-moya), but I don't think it applies here...

Can you help?

Process output is:

```
> ./getweathermap.php 

Request query parameters should be: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4215110&units=imperial&appid=my_api_key
cUrl error (#0): <br>
cUrl verbose information:
*   Trying 192.241.245.161:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.openweathermap.org (192.241.245.161) port 80 (#0)
&gt; POST /data/2.5/weather HTTP/1.1
Host: api.openweathermap.org
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
&lt; HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
&lt; Server: openresty
&lt; Date: Sun, 27 Feb 2022 01:45:01 GMT
&lt; Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
&lt; Content-Length: 107
&lt; Connection: keep-alive
&lt; X-Cache-Key: /data/2.5/weather?
&lt; Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
&lt; Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
&lt; Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
&lt; 
* Connection #0 to host api.openweathermap.org left intact

Array
(
    [cod] => 401
    [message] => Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.
)
```

Comment: In the example you've given, the `?id=4215110&units=metric&appid=my_api_key` is on the URL in the querystring. Therefore they're not POST values (which are carried in the request body), they're querystring parameter values (sometimes referred to as GET values, even when the overall request is sent using POST). I don't see anything at https://openweathermap.org/current which says you need to use POST or send the values in the request body. A simple GET with the variables on the URL querystring should work fine.

Comment: `I can copy the value in the "Request query paraemters..." line and paste them into a browser to get the correct results without error`...yes because that a) puts the values on the querystring and b) a request from your browser always causes a GET, not a POST.